# PHP Table echo empty td

Tags: php, html-table

Why would it empty an empty td and work properly.  If there are is no data, it pushes the next row data up the column. Please suggest me how to fix it.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($cheads[$keys[0]]); $i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    for($k = 0; $k < count($keys); $k++){
        echo "<td>";
        if(array_key_exists($i, $cheads[$keys[$k]])){
            echo $cheads[$keys[$k]][$i]['Data'];
        }else{
            echo "N/A";
        }
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

[image]

Data set:
[image]

```
Array ( [Last Name] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Field] => Last Name [Data] => 1 [User] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [Field] => Last Name [Data] => 1 [User] => 5 ) [2] => Array ( [Field] => Last Name [Data] => 1 [User] => 5 ) [3] => Array ( [Field] => Last Name [Data] => Yo [User] => 5 ) [4] => Array ( [Field] => Last Name [Data] => Test [User] => 5 ) ) [Phone Name] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Field] => Phone Name [Data] => 2 [User] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [Field] => Phone Name [Data] => 2 [User] => 5 ) [2] => Array ( [Field] => Phone Name [Data] => 2 [User] => 5 ) [3] => Array ( [Field] => Phone Name [Data] => Yo [User] => 5 ) [4] => Array ( [Field] => Phone Name [Data] => [User] => 5 ) ) [Address Name] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Field] => Address Name [Data] => 3 [User] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [Field] => Address Name [Data] => 3 [User] => 5 ) [2] => Array ( [Field] => Address Name [Data] => Yo [User] => 5 ) [3] => Array ( [Field] => Address Name [Data] => [User] => 5 ) ) [Description] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Field] => Description [Data] => 4 [User] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [Field] => Description [Data] => 4 [User] => 5 ) [2] => Array ( [Field] => Description [Data] => 4 [User] => 5 ) [3] => Array ( [Field] => Description [Data] => Yo [User] => 5 ) [4] => Array ( [Field] => Description [Data] => [User] => 5 ) ) [Fruit Type] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Field] => Fruit Type [Data] => Peanuts [User] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [Field] => Fruit Type [Data] => Apple [User] => 5 ) ) )
```

Comment: You use `count($cheads[$keys[0]])` in the first loop and in the echo, but in the second for loop you use `count($keys)`. Is that correct?

Comment: Counts are used correctly, if I do -1 in any of the count, it stops displaying last columns or last rows which has some data

Comment: I have attached the data set I have

Comment: Probably just an HTML issue. Some browsers won't use up the room for empty `<td>`'s. You'll probably have to put some type of space or 1px image and check for empty. Are you looking to show the empty rows in `<td>`'s with empty lines throughout, is that the goal here? If not, then I haven't grasped the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am echoing N/A if index not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to change how I was getting data in my array. I used associated arrays with a different approach.

Before:

```
cheads:    Array ( 
[Last Name] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [Field] => Last Name [Data] => 1 [User] => 5 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [Field] => Last Name [Data] => 1 [User] => 5 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [Field] => Last Name [Data] => 1 [User] => 5 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [Field] => Last Name [Data] => Yo [User] => 5 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [Field] => Last Name [Data] => Test [User] => 5 ) ) 

[Phone Name] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [Field] => Phone Name [Data] => 2 [User] => 5 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [Field] => Phone Name [Data] => 2 [User] => 5 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [Field] => Phone Name [Data] => 2 [User] => 5 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [Field] => Phone Name [Data] => Yo [User] => 5 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [Field] => Phone Name [Data] => [User] => 5 ) ) 

[Address Name] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [Field] => Address Name [Data] => 3 [User] => 5 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [Field] => Address Name [Data] => 3 [User] => 5 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [Field] => Address Name [Data] => Yo [User] => 5 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [Field] => Address Name [Data] => [User] => 5 ) ) 
[Description] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [Field] => Description [Data] => 4 [User] => 5 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [Field] => Description [Data] => 4 [User] => 5 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [Field] => Description [Data] => 4 [User] => 5 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [Field] => Description [Data] => Yo [User] => 5 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [Field] => Description [Data] => [User] => 5 ) ) 
[Fruit Type] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [Field] => Fruit Type [Data] => Peanuts [User] => 5 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [Field] => Fruit Type [Data] => Apple [User] => 5 ) ) )
```

After:

```
Matrix:   Array ( 
[D2AA0FA4-4F91-4757-9D27-9F65E0390EF1] => Array ( [Last Name] => 1 [Phone Name] => 1 [Address Name] => 1 [Description] => 1 ) 
[182EDD25-89CE-40F0-87AE-53D218CD0A1F] => Array ( [Last Name] => 2 [Phone Name] => 2 [Address Name] => 2 [Description] => 2 ) 
[59EF4DA3-0D3B-4F37-A415-10DD414351A7] => Array ( [Last Name] => 3 [Phone Name] => 3 [Address Name] => 3 [Description] => 3 [Fruit Type] => Apple ) 
[1C7B67E2-9230-4215-B990-C366077DA6C3] => Array ( [Last Name] => 5 [Phone Name] => 5 [Address Name] => 5 [Description] => 5 ) )
```

I had an extra Identifier field for identifying each data by user. I made them parent keys and for each identifier I added all fields data under them making field-type key as well for each child data.

Before this I had collect all the keys in another array, I iterated through it and simply echoed like this:

```
foreach ($matrix as $key => $value) {

    echo "<tr>";

    for($i = 0; $i < count($cheads); $i++){

        $head = $cheads[$i];

        if(isset($value[$head])){
            echo "<td>";
            echo $value[$head];
            echo "</td>";
        }else{
            echo "<td>";
            echo "NA";
            echo "</td>";
        }

    }
    echo "<td><a href='?action=edit&guid=$key'>Edit</a></td>";
    echo "<tr>";

}
```

Result:

[image]

Using associative key and a different approach did it for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually nothing wrong with your PHP. The problem is stemming from how your array was generated.

You're identifying rows based on their numeric array key index, so when a row is missing, instead of skipping the numeric index it uses the next in line causing everything to get out of sync.

Based on your diagram, you're expecting all the 'Yo' records to belong together, so you'd have to keep the array keys in sync. That would mean skipping index 2 in 'Phone Name' and also skipping indices 0, 1, and 2 in 'Fruit Type'

This

```
  'Address Name' => Array (
    '0' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => 3, 'User' => 5 ),
    '1' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => 3, 'User' => 5 ),
    '2' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => 'Yo', 'User' => 5 ),
    '3' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => null, 'User' => 5 )
  ),
```

and

```
 'Fruit Type' => Array (
    '0' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Fruit Type', 'Data' => 'Peanuts', 'User' => 5 ),
    '1' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Fruit Type', 'Data' => 'Apple', 'User' => 5 ) 
  )
```

would become

```
  'Address Name' => Array (
    '0' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => 3, 'User' => 5 ),
    '1' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => 3, 'User' => 5 ),
    '3' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => 'Yo', 'User' => 5 ),
    '4' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => null, 'User' => 5 )
  ),

  'Fruit Type' => Array (
    '3' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Fruit Type', 'Data' => 'Peanuts', 'User' => 5 ),
    '4' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Fruit Type', 'Data' => 'Apple', 'User' => 5 ) 
  )
```

Because there's no other identifying information in each record, then it's impossible to solve it otherwise (it's odd that every User is 5).

One alternative solution would be to change to using an associative key index, but then your whole PHP row construction method falls apart because it depends on numeric keys.

Another alternative that may solve your problem is that I noticed the data you provided contains an additional row than what is in your diagram. In this extra row, instead of missing data, the values are actually inserted as `null` so if you clear out the first records, then your script should work so long as new data coming in is created the same way (by inserting nulls). However, then your "N/A" column will never be populated because it's shown as a blank cell.

You script as is:

```
<?php

$cheads = Array (
  'Last Name' => Array (
    '0' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Last Name', 'Data' => 1, 'User' => 5 ),
    '1' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Last Name', 'Data' => 1, 'User' => 5 ),
    '2' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Last Name', 'Data' => 1, 'User' => 5 ),
    '3' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Last Name', 'Data' => 'Yo', 'User' => 5 ),
    '4' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Last Name', 'Data' => 'Test', 'User' => 5 )
  ),
  'Phone Name' => Array (
    '0' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Phone Name', 'Data' => 2, 'User' => 5 ),
    '1' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Phone Name', 'Data' => 2, 'User' => 5 ),
    '2' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Phone Name', 'Data' => 2, 'User' => 5 ),
    '3' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Phone Name', 'Data' => 'Yo', 'User' => 5 ),
    '4' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Phone Name', 'Data' => null, 'User' => 5 )
  ),
  'Address Name' => Array (
    '0' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => 3, 'User' => 5 ),
    '1' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => 3, 'User' => 5 ),
    '2' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => 'Yo', 'User' => 5 ),
    '3' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => null, 'User' => 5 )
  ),
  'Description' => Array (
    '0' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Description', 'Data' => 4, 'User' => 5 ),
    '1' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Description', 'Data' => 4, 'User' => 5 ),
    '2' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Description', 'Data' => 4, 'User' => 5 ),
    '3' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Description', 'Data' => 'Yo', 'User' => 5 ),
    '4' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Description', 'Data' => null, 'User' => 5 ) 
  ),
  'Fruit Type' => Array (
    '0' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Fruit Type', 'Data' => 'Peanuts', 'User' => 5 ),
    '1' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Fruit Type', 'Data' => 'Apple', 'User' => 5 ) 
  )
);

$keys = ['Last Name', 'Phone Name', 'Address Name', 'Description', 'Fruit Type'];
?>

<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <?php
        foreach ($keys as $key)
          echo "<th>$key</th>";
      ?>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<?php
for($i = 0; $i < count($cheads[$keys[0]]); $i++){ // foreach 'Last Name'
    echo "<tr>";
    for($k = 0; $k < count($keys); $k++){ // foreach $keys
        echo "<td>";
        if(array_key_exists($i, $cheads[$keys[$k]])){
            echo $cheads[$keys[$k]][$i]['Data'];
        }else{
            echo "N/A";
        }
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Last Name</th><th>Phone Name</th><th>Address Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Fruit Type</th>    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>Peanuts</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>Apple</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>Yo</td><td>4</td><td>N/A</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yo</td><td>Yo</td><td></td><td>Yo</td><td>N/A</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test</td><td></td><td>N/A</td><td></td><td>N/A</td></tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

When using the array constructed with synchronized numeric keys.

```
$cheads = Array (
  'Last Name' => Array (
    '0' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Last Name', 'Data' => 1, 'User' => 5 ),
    '1' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Last Name', 'Data' => 1, 'User' => 5 ),
    '2' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Last Name', 'Data' => 1, 'User' => 5 ),
    '3' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Last Name', 'Data' => 'Yo', 'User' => 5 ),
    '4' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Last Name', 'Data' => 'Test', 'User' => 5 )
  ),
  'Phone Name' => Array (
    '0' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Phone Name', 'Data' => 2, 'User' => 5 ),
    '1' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Phone Name', 'Data' => 2, 'User' => 5 ),
    '2' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Phone Name', 'Data' => 2, 'User' => 5 ),
    '3' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Phone Name', 'Data' => 'Yo', 'User' => 5 ),
    '4' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Phone Name', 'Data' => null, 'User' => 5 )
  ),
  'Address Name' => Array (
    '0' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => 3, 'User' => 5 ),
    '1' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => 3, 'User' => 5 ),
    '3' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => 'Yo', 'User' => 5 ),
    '4' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Address Name', 'Data' => null, 'User' => 5 )
  ),
  'Description' => Array (
    '0' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Description', 'Data' => 4, 'User' => 5 ),
    '1' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Description', 'Data' => 4, 'User' => 5 ),
    '2' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Description', 'Data' => 4, 'User' => 5 ),
    '3' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Description', 'Data' => 'Yo', 'User' => 5 ),
    '4' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Description', 'Data' => null, 'User' => 5 ) 
  ),
  'Fruit Type' => Array (
    '3' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Fruit Type', 'Data' => 'Peanuts', 'User' => 5 ),
    '4' => Array ( 'Field' => 'Fruit Type', 'Data' => 'Apple', 'User' => 5 ) 
  )
);
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Last Name</th><th>Phone Name</th><th>Address Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Fruit Type</th>    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>N/A</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>N/A</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>N/A</td><td>4</td><td>N/A</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yo</td><td>Yo</td><td>Yo</td><td>Yo</td><td>Peanuts</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Apple</td></tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```